# Help integrating, is there a way without an error function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, error-function

I have to integrate the following:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(\sqrt{(\pi)}l)^3} \exp({\frac{- (\textbf{r} + \textbf{r}_0)^2}{l^2}}) \exp({-i\textbf{q}. \textbf{r}}) d\textbf{r}$$.

The result is supposedly $$\exp({\frac{-l^2 q^2}{4}}) \exp{i\textbf{q}.\textbf{r}_0}$$

but I am unsure how to evaluate this with the vectors

EDIT:
It's from a physics paper and I'll post the full expressions leading to that integral: $$D(q) = \int_0^\infty d\textbf{r} [ (D_v - D_c) |\psi(\textbf{r})|^2 ] \exp^{-i\textbf{q}. \textbf{r}}$$ it then uses Gaussian ground-state wavefunctions given by: $$\psi(\textbf{r}) = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{\pi} l)^{3/2} }\exp(-{\frac{(\textbf{r} + \textbf{r}_0)^2}{2l^2}}).$$ You can ignore the $D_v - D_c$ and $(\sqrt{\pi} l)^{3/2}$ factors if you wish as they're just constants. The integral $D(q)$ is then given by the first equation of the post.

Comment: You have $d\mathbf{r}$ in the integrand but only one integration. What is the meaning of your expression?

Comment: @Sal Hi, it's from a physics paper, but there is a second case which seems to be more consistent with the notation, I have edited the post so it is hopefully clearer. Thanks for any feedback or tips!

Comment: When you write $\int_0^\infty$, are you sure about the bounds of integration? It looks like it may be an integral over higher dimensions because of the bold notation throughout (usually reserved for vectors). Anyhow, the integral is essentially the Fourier transform of a Gaussian function, which is itself a Gaussian with reciprocal standard deviation and inversely proportional height.

Answer (score 1):

The essential step is to put the exponentials together, and then "complete the square" in $\mathbf{r}$, writing $$-\frac{(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0})}{l^2}-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}$$ as $$-\frac{(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{2}il^2\mathbf{q})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{2}il^2\mathbf{q})}{l^2}+i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{4}l^2\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{q}.$$ Now, when you integrate over space (which I think is what is required here) the Gaussian just gives 1, even though it is shifted to centre about $\mathbf{r_0}+\tfrac{1}{2}il^2\mathbf{q}$, and you are left with the factors you want.

In detail, and using clearer notation for what I think is meant by the problem $$\int_{\text{all of space}} \frac{1}{(\sqrt{(\pi)}l)^3} \exp({\frac{- (\textbf{r} + \textbf{r}_0)^2}{l^2}}) \exp({-i\textbf{q}. \textbf{r}}) \, dV $$
$$=\int \frac{1}{(\sqrt{(\pi)}l)^3} \exp(-\frac{(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{2}il^2\mathbf{q})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{2}il^2\mathbf{q})}{l^2}+i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{4}l^2\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{q})  \, dV $$
taking out the factors independent of $\mathbf{r}$
$$=\exp{(i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{4}l^2\mathbf{q}} \cdot \mathbf{q})\int \frac{1}{(\sqrt{(\pi)}l)^3} \exp(-\frac{(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{2}il^2\mathbf{q})\cdot(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{2}il^2\mathbf{q})}{l^2})  \, dV  $$
and substituting $\mathbf{r'}=\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{2}il^2\mathbf{q}$, noting that translating the whole of space just gives the whole of space,
$$=\exp{(i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r_0}-\tfrac{1}{4}l^2\mathbf{q}} \cdot \mathbf{q})\int_{\text{all of space}} \frac{1}{(\sqrt{(\pi)}l)^3} \exp(-\frac{\mathbf{r'}\cdot\mathbf{r'}}{l^2})  \, dV'  $$ and the Gaussian integral is equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems like your notation is much clearer than the papers and it definitely makes sense.